# How can I connect my proxy server with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

When I use the Python request module, it is only proxying a certain website. How can I use requests to connect to each website?
Best regards.

Comment: `requests.get(..., proxy={"http" : proxy_address, "https": proxy_address})`. You may also try to set it in `requests.Session()` and maybe it will use it for all requests.

Comment: Requests.session wants specific url. Doesnt work but thanks for your feedback.

Comment: what URL do you mean in `requests.Session` ? `s = requests.Session()` and `s.proxies = {"http" : proxy_address, "https": proxy_address}` and it doesn't need any specific url - only proxy address. And later you can use `s.get(...)` with specific URL but proxy should already remeber.